# MySQL query indexing with timestamp structure

Tags: mysql, indexing

I was wondering what the best way of storing user queries correlated with timestamps in MySQL was. Let's say I have just two inputs, a user's "query" and "timestamp"...

I could create a MySQL table with fields (`id`, `query`, `count`, `timestamp_list`), where:

`id` is unique identifier of the query,
`query` is the literal query string,
`count` is the (constantly-UPDATEd) number of times that query is entered, and
`timestamp_list` is a LONGTEXT or something with a list of times that query was searched.

Is there a better way to correlate these using indexing I'm not familiar with? It seems like storing a list of timestamps in a LONGTEXT is dumb, but easy; perhaps I should create a separate table like:

`id`
`query_id`  (correlates to `id` in first table)
`timestamp`

And I can join results with the first table. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to record the timestamp when each query was performed, i'd suggest you have 2 tables:

```
 tbl_queries
  - id       INT
  - query    VARCHAR

 tbl_queries_performed
  - id         INT AUTOINCREMENT
  - query_id   INT
  - timestamp  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Each time you want to record a query, check if it's in `tbl_queries` already and then save an entry in `tbl_queries_performed` with the query_id respectively